# Is this the proper way of using async/await?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1

I am implementing a .Net Core API using Services-Repository and I am making some calls asynchronously, this is a representation of what I have.

```
    //** Controller
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategory()
    {
        var categories = await categoryService.GetAllAsync();

        var categoriesVM = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>>(categories);

        return Ok(categoriesVM);
    }

    //** Service
    public async Task<List<Category>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await categoryRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();
    }

    //** Repository
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {            
        return DbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();  
    }
```

As you can see I make async calls all the way, but not in my Repository. Is this a proper way of using async/await calls, or should I change my repo to something like this:

```
    public virtual async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAll()
    {            
        return await DbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your repository to look like that? You might find some compiler errors preventing it.

The way you have it set up now is fine.